# How to force logout a user other then current_user using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-token-auth

I need to create a functionality at admin site which allow an admin to force_logout any user.

I am using devise token based authentication and tried `sign_out user` method, It does not work.

Comment: `sign_out` is just a test helper.  Vanilla Devise does not have any built in provisions for this and I don't think devise_token_auth does either. You would have to do something like adding a boolean column to the model and overriding the Warden strategy to reject the user when they attempt to log in if that flag is set.

Comment: @max what if I just reset the token in user table, I have disabled the token_change policy to persist.